# restrict the default url of a web application

Tags: java, tomcat, jakarta-ee, web

upon deploying a web application in Tomcat one can access it at the url http://localhost:8080/Application_name I want to disable/restrict access through this url as I have defined different url patterns/ servlet mapping in web.xml. How to achieve this.

Comment: Add a redirection rule maybe?

Comment: No. With `localhost` others can't access

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza how can i do the same. I want that the users should not be able to access the default address of web application

Comment: @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ what kind of good web app could be if only accessed through localhost? :)

Comment: @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ to be more specific i want to restrict the access https://server:port/app_id

Comment: In web.xml, can't you add one more mapping and redirect or return a 404 from the server for that mapping?  Or keep an index file which just says  'this not the page you're looking for'?

Comment: @prabugp can i do that for default web application url. I thought in web.xml we can only specify the various url patterns

Answer (score 1):

I guess that's what you want:

1. Edit tomcat/conf/server.xml.
2. Specify a bind **address** for that connector:

   ```
   <Connector 
       port="8080" 
       protocol="HTTP/1.1" 
       address="127.0.0.1"
       connectionTimeout="20000" 
       redirectPort="8443" 
     />
   ```

In this case, I'm setting 127.0.0.1 as IP address, so you can call through 127.0.0.1:8080/Application_name

But you can put an valid IP and that's how it will work.

Comment: Is there a way to do in web.xml

Comment: I don't think so. The 'web.xml' file is a file of the application. The 'server.xml' is a file of the server. I don't think that you can restrict this to one single application on server, and even if you could, 'web.xml' would not do that.